# Days difference from html5 form date

Tags: html, forms, datepicker, datediff, days

how can obtain de difference of two dates in days from an html5 form with date picker ?

i have tried with something like this, that didn't work yet: it showed NaN (Not a Number)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form oninput="c.value=b.value-a.value;">
            date a:<input type="date" id="a" value="">
            date b:<input type="date" id="b" value="">
            <br>
            c = b-a in days:<output name="c" for="a b"></output><br>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `"return (document.getElementBydId('a').value - document.getElementBydId('b').value);"`? Check the W3C for the features; http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-output-element

Comment: Thanks!. that is in javascript ?, would be possible to do in html5 native? I'm reading the W3C !  ;)

Comment: Yes it is. But you can only do calculations based on that. If you want to do date calculations, you need a more complex structure. To convert both input values to a date format or microtime and check their differences. You can't just do "dateA"-"dateB" in HTML. What you could do is make dropdown boxes and convert all the values (year/month/day/hours/minutes/seconds) to microtime and then subtract the two dates from each other. It will make a long calculation in the `oninput` attribute tho. Might become hard to read.

Comment: would be a better way to do this?:                             <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <form oninput="c.value=(b.valueAsDate-a.valueAsDate)/24/3600/1000;">
   date a:<input type="date" id="a" value="">
   date b:<input type="date" id="b" value="">
   <br>
   c = b-a in days:<output name="c" for="a b"></output><br>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: But what date-format are you expecting to be inserted into a free field? People can type anything in there? Also there are many different datetime-notations. There are so many variables that you can't rely on what you have. Even that what you show in the previous comment doesn't work. `String - String = NaN` is the reason; like `"2012-01-01 20:20:12" - "2012-01-02 08:10:39" = NaN` ;)

Comment: should the browser help with the type date, preventing to the user insert something different?

Comment: tried with this and worked:   <form oninput="c.value=(b.valueAsDate-a.valueAsDate)/24/3600/1000;">

Comment: Good to hear. Good luck coding :)

Comment: thanks for making me read and think more   ;)

Comment: You should answer/accept you own question in this case. So other people who search for this can instantly know how to solve it, as they won't always check all comments :)